# Date difference in days no matter year

Tags: php

How could I calculate date difference between two dates without paying attention to year?

So for example if I have `$first = '20/08/2019'` and `$second = '10/08/2020'`, the function should return 10, even though the `$second` date is one year ahead of `$first`?

Comment: Use php date_diff function : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php

Comment: The requirement is a bit weird.

Comment: @xNoJustice It would return more then 10 days, it would add 365 for a year also

Comment: @vivek_23 It sure is, but that's what I need

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to do this. Just get the bigger year (in my case I know it will always be for the `$first` date) and recreate `$second` date using that year:

```
$first = new \DateTime('10/08/2020');
$first_year = $first->format('Y');
$second = new \DateTime('20/08/2019'); 
$second_without_year = $second->format('m-d');
$second_modified = new \DateTime($first_year.'-'.$second_without_year);
    
$first->diff($second_modified)->format("%R%a");
```

Answer (score 0):

By ignoring the year, I suppose we include leap years as well. In that case, the below code might work:

```
$first = date_create('20-08-2019');
$second = date_create('10-08-2020');
$interval = date_diff($first, $second);
$diff = abs($interval->format("%R%a"));
if($diff>365){
  $diff = intval($diff/365);
}
```

To ignore the leap year days, subtract the number of leap years between the years from $diff

Comment: Tried it, it won't work. For given days in my question, the difference is 356 and consequently code inside if loop wouldn't be executed for this case